# How do bind inner query results from service.js to outer variable in Angular.js directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js

Using [angular-seed project:](https://github.com/angular/angular-seed)
In directives.js

```
var names = [];
Animals.query(function(data){ // Animals.query() from service.js
  console.log(data.Names); // output > [Object, Object..., Object]  
  names = data.Names; // attempt to bind to outer variable
});
console.log(names); // output > []
```

I can see the data there but I need it outside the function.  How do I get it outside the function?  console.log(names); happens before console.log(data.Names);
I know it has to do with closures and maybe callbacks and I've tried many things and but I can't seem to get them to work for my case.  I end up with an ever expanding mess of functions wrapped in callbacks wrapped in functions with still no binding to outside variable.  I don't want to 'pollute the global namespace' but I need ahold of the data outside the inner function.  The end-purpose is to get the data to be available for d3.js processing.  There must be a simpler way.  Can someone please help me with this particular case?

Comment: If you need to share the same data with several components, put it in a service.

Comment: ah from rereading your question itself you should be able to inject the service into the directive to get the data (or setup a watch to watch the service and update the directive).  I think the more "proper" way to go would be to have the controller setup scope variables that are passed into the directives but I may be wrong

Comment: Yes, to both of the above and comments.  I misunderstood where and how data should be loaded with respect to directives- I see now that as Paulo said the data should come from a service outside the directive and passed to the directive via a controller as shaunhusain says, and used the way Joe describes below.  Also, I believe now that route-providers makes it possible for the directive to not fire until the service is finished and triggers the controller.  I hope to update this when I get a proper example working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope I'm not misunderstanding you: you've already created (I assume) a function Animals as a service. Why don't you inject that in the controller of the directive's scope?

as in :

```
function Controller($scope, Animals){
  $scope.names = [];
  $scope.updateD3viz = function(){
    // do your d3 stuff here
    $scope.names = Animals.query(); // or whatever
  }
}
```

`$scope` will be accessible from the directive's `link(scope,elem,attrs)` method.

I had to do something similar (angular and d3) and i ended up having a d3 graph as a controller's scope property to make sure it was included in angular's lifecycle.

Comment: Thanks, that just might work! - I was able to bind to $scope.xxx in another area but for some reason can't get it to bind to something separate outside the function.  And looking at your approach now - I think I've gotten tunnel vision on solving this problem, and your answer may have helped dislodge my thinking.  As soon as I get a chance to work on it again, I'll check off your answer :)

Comment: Yes, thank you - right or wrong, I did give up trying to get the data modeled outside of the functions scope and modeled it inside the scope.

Comment: Update: although it works, my approach above is not the 'proper' way to do it.  The way I'm doing it now, as you describe above, is put the external query into a service, which the route provider waits on and when the data is ready passes it to the controller which then the directive can pass on to the d3.js processing inside it.  I said a bunch of words like a parrot does, but don't know what I'm talking about :)